# Susy - get static span width in fluid container

Tags: css, sass, grid, susy

I'm building a website using susy fluid grid container. But some of my interface elements require fixed width. So having these settings:

```
$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  container: rem-calc(1680),
  gutters: 28px/112px,
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  gutter-position: split
);
```

I would like to easly get for example 8 column span, but staticly. So @include span(8 of 12) would result with precentage value, which is fine, but in certain cases I'd like to get the static value (based on container fixed max width ofcourse).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your susy global settings above you can add:

```
math: static
```

But in order to do so you need to include the column-width object as well.

So let's say you want to have each column with 40px width, using your example it goes like this:

```
$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  ...
  math: static,
  column-width: 40px
);
```

When you do `@include span` instead of using % basis, it will use px base which as you want it as static.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but you missunderstood my question. I want to extract static width for certain elements, not whole layout, which is fluid, and global math needs to stay fluid.

Comment: If you want the global math to stay fluid you can do it locally using the shortcode:

`@include span (8 of 12 static 40px)`

It will render math as static and column-width as 40px

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can pass in `static` as an argument for any Susy function or mixin where you want static output — `@include span(8 of 12 static)` — as long as you have a `column-width` or `container` set. (don't set both, or there's potential for conflicts)

update: oh, I see this was mentioned in a comment above...